# Plotly trend lines for each data set not working

Tags: python, plotly

I can plot a trend line that for example works on the min/max of all the data, but I want a trend line for each group (color) of points. However it doesn't work when I change `trendline_scope="overall"` to `trendline_scope="trace"`. I get a mess, instead of I am expecting.

```
fig = px.scatter(df, "Date", y="Number of X", color="Technology", labels={
                     "Date": "Reported Date",
                     "Number of Qubits": "Number of X",
                     "markersize": 50,
                     "s": 50,
                     "title": "X"

                 }, trendline="expanding", trendline_options=dict(function="max"), trendline_scope="trace")
```

Comment: What's going wrong?

If I reproduce it with some random data, I get one trendline when "overall" is specified, and one for each trace when "trace" is specified, in a way that seems to do it's job. Did you intend to use the "max" function?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot and a drawing of what you expect/want?